# Filling Closed Shapes

Tags: unity, mathematics, projection, mesh

Game Engine : Unity 5.1
Developing on Windows 7

Hello,

I am using Vectrosity to draw some some shapes on screen run time. I also need to fill these shapes and none of them are really trivial shapes. So after doing some research I figured the best way would be to do it by creating a run-time mesh. Now this almost works for me but has a big issue.

This is my process.

1) I have defined my complex shapes as a set of 2D vertices that I extracted from Illustrator. These vertices I feed to the Vectrosity's Catmul spline function to create my shapes.

2) I then project these vertices in the real space using ScreenToWorldPoint to get 3D vertices.

3) I then pass these vertices to a program that Triangulates these points to a mesh (I use the classic Triangulate script on wiki)

4) I then clean up a little and align

Now all this works well if the camera is not rotated and the forward vector of the camera is orthogonal to the XY plane. The moment I rotate the camera the alignment of the mesh and the vector lines is completely gone.

Here is the image of the vectorline and mesh when the camera is not rotated

[image]

And here is the image when the camera is rotated

[image]

Here is the function that projects the point into 3D space

```
 void DrawPolygon () {

     Vector2[] tempVerts = new Vector2[allLinePoints.Count];

     for(int i=0; i<allLinePoints.Count; i++) {

         Vector3 projectedPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(allLinePoints[i].x, allLinePoints[i].y, 10.0f));
         tempVerts[i] = new Vector2(projectedPoint.x, projectedPoint.y);

     }

     polyTarget.SendMessage("Create", tempVerts);
 }
```

This message is sent to a generic Triangulation script. Here it is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

 public class CreatePolygon : MonoBehaviour {


 public Material meshMaterial;

 public void Create (Vector2[] verts) {

     Triangulator tr = new Triangulator (verts);
     int[] indices = tr.Triangulate ();

     // Create the Vector3 vertices
     Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[verts.Length];
     for (int i=0; i<vertices.Length; i++) {
         vertices[i] = new Vector3(verts[i].x, verts[i].y, 0);
     }

     // Create the mesh
     Mesh msh = new Mesh();
     msh.vertices = vertices;
     msh.triangles = indices;

     msh.RecalculateNormals();
     msh.RecalculateBounds();


     // Set up game object with mesh;
     gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
     MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;
     filter.mesh = msh;

     GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = meshMaterial;
     StartCoroutine (FlipNormal ());
 }

 public void ResetMesh (Vector2[] verts) {

     Triangulator tr = new Triangulator (verts);
     int[] indices = tr.Triangulate ();

     // Create the Vector3 vertices
     Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[verts.Length];
     for (int i=0; i<vertices.Length; i++) {
         vertices[i] = new Vector3(verts[i].x, verts[i].y, 0);
     }

     // Create the mesh
     Mesh msh = new Mesh();
     msh.vertices = vertices;
     msh.triangles = indices;

     msh.RecalculateNormals();
     msh.RecalculateBounds();


     // Set up game object with mesh;
     MeshFilter filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
     filter.mesh = msh;

     GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = meshMaterial;
     StartCoroutine (FlipNormal ());
 }

 IEnumerator FlipNormal() {

     yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
     Mesh mesh = (GetComponent<MeshFilter> () as MeshFilter).mesh;
     mesh.uv = mesh.uv.Select(o => new Vector2(1 - o.x, o.y)).ToArray();
     mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();

 }
}
```

Now this seems to be an obvious problem to have but I am just not being able to crack it. I have a feeling the solution is some mathematics that is completely escaping me right now. Can someone please help and point me to the right direction. I need to be able to align the mesh to the outline even when the camera is rotated.

Comment: Have you tried making your meshes a child of the camera, so there is no relative rotation between them no matter how the camera moves?

Comment: Thanks for the input but no luck. It still doesn't align with the outline. If I parent the mesh to the camera, the the rotation is correct but the alignment still doesn't work. The scale of the mesh that's created is also wrong. I am guessing this is because of the perspective camera. Is there anything else you can think of that I can try.

Comment: Is there some basic math with the projection matrices etc that I am missing?

Comment: The first image you showed doesn't appear to have any scale or alignment mismatch — is this a new problem introduced when parenting to the camera? If so, you might be mixing up your coordinate spaces.

Comment: The first image is when the camera is orthogonal to the XY plane. When it is not rotated, I don't have a problem. The alignment issue only happens when the camera is rotated. This is the same when parenting to the camera. The alignment is fine as long as the camera is not rotated.